# Coinbase Pro API client_oid always empty

Tags: uuid, coinbase-api

I've run into an issue using the Coinbase Pro sandbox API to test my software.
When placing orders, I POST a `client_oid` field along with the rest of the body to the REST API, the order gets filled properly but when the `received` message arrives through the websocket stream, the client_oid is always an empty string.

Anyone knows why is that and how to fix this?

Example data POSTed when placing the order:

```
{
  "type": "market",
  "side": "buy",
  "product_id": "BTC-EUR",
  "funds": "1000",
  "client_oid": "dev_node-order-1"
}
```

And here's the matching websocket message of type `received`:

```
{
  "type": "received",
  "side": "buy",
  "product_id": "BTC-EUR",
  "time": "2021-08-15T16:57:29.079657Z",
  "sequence": 52030416,
  "profile_id": "[MY-PROFILE-ID]",
  "user_id": "[USER-ID]",
  "order_id": "d1f60730-8960-495e-a7eb-cd37baa46768",
  "order_type": "market",
  "funds": "995.0245866076",
  "client_oid": ""
}
```

As you can see the received `client_oid` is empty, any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that the `client_oid` needs to be of the [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) format, for example `9bffcb70-13ea-11ec-abc7-7dfab310af81`, if not of this format the field is ignored.